# Solve by using method of variation of constants

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

$y''=sin(x)-cos(x)$

I tried integrating twice and got the general solution, but I need to do it with the method of variation of constants, does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

First we solve the homogenous equation:

$$y_h''=0 \rightarrow y=C_1x+C_2$$

Then we solve for a particular solution of the specific equation:

$$y_p=C(x) y_h$$
$$y_p''=C''(x)y_h+2C'(x)y'_h+C(x)y''_h=\sin(x)-\cos(x)$$

From here we can simplify and find:

$$C(x)=\frac{-\sin(x)}{C_1x+C_2}+\frac{\cos(x)}{C_1x+C_2}$$

So the general solution is:

$$y=y_p+y_h= \left(\frac{-\sin(x)}{C_1x+C_2}+\frac{\cos(x)}{C_1x+C_2}\right)(C_1x+C_2) + C_1x+C_2$$
$$y = -\sin(x)+\cos(x)+ C_1x+C_2$$